# What is a Homotopy of Maps in the Sense of Quillen-Model-Structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, model-categories

I am fairly new to model categories, so apologies if this question has an obvious solution or if it doesn't even make sense...

Naive homotopy in $\mathsf{Top}$ (using the unit interval $I$ and maps $X\times I \rightarrow Y$ respectively $X \rightarrow Y^I$) gives rise to the *Hurewicz-Model-structure* on $\mathsf{Top}$ with
$$\begin{align*}
\text{weak equivalences} &= \text{homotopy equivalences}\\
\text{fibrations} &= \text{Hurewicz-fibrations}\\
\text{cofibrations} &= \text{(closed) Hurewicz-cofibrations}
\end{align*}$$

After introducing higher homotopy groups one might become interested in classifying spaces not up to homotopy equivalence, but up to *weak homotopy equivalences*. Hence one studies the *Quillen-Model-Structure* given by
$$\begin{align*}
\text{weak equivalences} &= \text{weak homotopy equivalences}\\
\text{fibrations} &= \text{Serre-fibrations}\\
\text{cofibrations} &= \text{induced notion of cofibrations}
\end{align*}$$

I read in [Dwyer Spalinski](https://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Spalinski/theories.pdf) (around section 4.1) that any model category gives rise to its own notion of homotopy of maps by considering cylinder objects / path objects in the following way:

> Maps $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ are *left-homotopic*, if there is *some* cylinder object $X \wedge I$ such that the extension problem
> $$\begin{matrix}
> X+X &\overset{f+g}{\longrightarrow}& Y\\
> {\scriptsize{i_0+i_1}}\downarrow&\nearrow\\
> X\wedge I
> \end{matrix}$$
> admits a solution. In a similiar fashion one defines being *right-homotopic* and both notions coincide if the objects involved are good enough ie. cofibrant respectively fibrant. Then taking the quotients of the Hom-sets by the equivalence relation given by this notion of homotopy yields the homotopy category.

Trying to apply this definition to the topological setting I get confused over the following aspects:

1. In the naive topological setting we only use the standard cylinders $X\times I$ to define homotopy, while in the Hurewicz-model categorical context we should have used a variety of possible cylinder objects. In retrospect it suffices, since the resulting category is a localization of $\mathsf{Top}$ at the (naive) homotopy equivalences ie. weak equivalences ie. (model theoretic) homotopy equivalences. But there has to be a more intuitive reason.
2. What happens in the case of the Quillen-model-structure? Naively in this context more maps should be homotopic than in the context of Hurewicz, as the class of both fibrations and weak equivalences are larger. Yet I read [example 3.5](https://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Spalinski/theories.pdf) so that the homotopy category $\operatorname{ho}_Q(\mathsf{Top}) \simeq \operatorname{ho}_Q(\mathsf{CW})$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{ho}_H(\mathsf{CW})$. The first equivalence is clear by CW-approximation, but the latter equivalence confuses me, since full and faithfulness implies that maps between CW-complexes are homotopic in the Quillen-context if and only if they are in the Hurewicz-context. Hence this question's title.

As always thank you very much for your patience.

PS: Ultimatively I would like to have a formal reason, why the properties of homotopy pushouts/pullbacks constructed in the Hurewicz-context carry over to the Quillen-context. Trying to figure this out, knowing more about their relation will help me alot.

Comment: Whitehead's theorem (the real one, not the formal one!) says that any weak homotopy equivalence between CW complexes is a homotopy equivalence, i.e. has a homotopy inverse in the classical sense.

Comment: Right, how could I miss that? So the localization argument can be used to answer both of my questions abstractly, but I still don’t get, why (naive) homotopy via the standard cylinder should agree with model theoretic homotopy via arbitrary cylinder objects?

Comment: There are a few "reasons" for it. One is that quotienting out by homotopy turns homotopy equivalences into isomorphisms, and conversely turning homotopy equivalences into isomorphisms forces homotopic maps to become equal. Another is that you can use a fibrancy–cofibrancy argument to convert any homotopy using a "non-standard" cylinder into a homotopy using the standard cylinder.

Comment: Well let me pose my problem differently: the standard cylinder is a cylinder for the H-context, hence it is for the Q-context. Defining homotopy internal to the model category homotopy equivalences are precisely the weak equivalences. Now if I can use fibrancy-cofibrancy arguments to restrict the def of internal htpy to a specific choice of cylinders (the standard cylinders in this case), the internal htpy of Quillen should agree with the internal htpy of Hurewicz (ie. naive htpy). Then both model structures (on $\mathsf{Top}$) share the same weak equivalences, which is nonsense

Comment: You cannot. Everything is cofibrant–fibrant in the Hurewicz model structure but this is not so for the Quillen model structure. In the first place the homotopy relation in a model category is not well behaved if you don't restrict to cofibrant–fibrant objects, even if you can define it more generally, so I think it is not a good idea to look at homotopy classes of maps between objects that are not cofibrant–fibrant.

Comment: I see. I guess the fibrant-cofibrant objects in the Quillen model structure are very close to CW-complexes and there the notions of homotopy do in fact agree... Anyway, thank you very much for your help!